# Count number of occurencies of a given substring in a file, Kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, substring

I have to write a function, which counts how many times does a substring occurs in the text and return a map (string - counts)

I tried to make it, using .contains, but it doesn't count multiple occurencies in a single word ("la" in "lalala"), and now I'm stuck with how to fix it.

```
fun countSubstrings(inputName: String, substrings: List<String>): Map<String, Int> {

    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
    var tempCounter = 0
    for (i in 0 until substrings.size) {

        for (line in File(inputName).readLines()) {

            for (word in line.split(" ")) {
                if (word.contains(substrings[i], true)) tempCounter++ 
            }
        }
        map.put(substrings[i], tempCounter)
        tempCounter = 0
    }
    return map
}
```

So, i expect this function to count words, 2-3 char substrings and even 1 char substrings.

Comment: Don't use contains, use `fun countSubstring(s: String, sub: String): Int = s.split(sub).size - 1`

Comment: Sorry for being a little inaccurate, but input and output of function are parts of a task.

Comment: @DanielM: This does not work correctly if the matches can overlap, e.g. there are two occurrences of "lala" in "lalala", but your solution returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use [indexOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of.html) to find position of first occurrence from given start position or -1 if no matches found. After that you can change start position and repeat it again. Then you will not have overlapping problem.

```
fun countMatches(text: String, template: String): Int {
    var cnt = 0
    var pos = 0
    while (true) {
        pos = text.indexOf(template, pos)
        if (pos != -1) {
            cnt++
            pos++
        } else {
            return cnt
        }
    }
}


fun countSubstrings(inputName: String, substrings: List<String>): Map<String, Int> {
    val mp = substrings.map { it to 0 }.toMap().toMutableMap()
    for (line in File(inputName).readLines()) {
        for (str in substrings) {
            if (str in mp) {
                mp[str] = (mp[str] ?: 0) + countMatches(line.toLowerCase(), str.toLowerCase())
            }
        }
    }
    return mp
}
```

But you should know 2 things:

1. Time complexity if O(n*m) where n and m lengths of such strings.
2. This is not very elegant solution, probably exists something better. But it works=)

Answer (score -1):

I mean, there is [StringUtils.html#countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) which is part of Apache commons.

```
 StringUtils.countMatches(null, *)       = 0
 StringUtils.countMatches("", *)         = 0
 StringUtils.countMatches("abba", null)  = 0
 StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "")    = 0
 StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "a")   = 2
 StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "ab")  = 1
 StringUtils.countMatches("abba", "xxx") = 0
```

Comment: Maybe they wanted a pure kotlin solution or maybe some bias against external libraries. It's SO, who knows.